Live translator for computer screen
I want to give a lecture in language X, and want to show live captions on screen in language Y. There are several phone-to-phone live translators available. I want an app that can work also on a PC. In the past Microsoft Translator used to work on PC, but not anymore. Anyone has suggestions? Ideally it would be free.
